# Table border issue in chrome after jquery drag stop

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, google-chrome

**Update** using `position: relative:` td, th
then, when dragging

[image]

Table border disappear after jquery drag

[image]

working fine in mozila and ie but not in chrome

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YTZrj/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>city</th>
    </tr>
      <tr class="person">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
      <tr class="person">
       <td>2</td>
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td>xyz</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table{
    border-collapse : collapse;
}

td, th{
    border : 1px solid #000;
    padding : 5px 20px;
}

th{
    background-color : #f3f3f3;
}

.drag {
    background-color : #f3f3f3;
    height : 20px;
    width : 100px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.person').draggable({
    helper : function(){
        return $('<div class="drag">Drag me</div>')
    },
    cursor : 'crosshair',
    cursorAt : {left : 50},
    start : function(){
        $(this).hide();
    },
    stop : function(){
          $(this).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing border-collapse from table css seems to have done the trick.

```
table{
      /* border-collapse : collapse */
}
```

Check out at http://jsfiddle.net/YTZrj/1/

Comment: i only checked on Chrome and in mine its working, the bottom border is showing fine

Answer (score 0):

```
table {border-collapse:separate;}
```

will make the table look a bit different but won't cause this problem anymore.

http://jsfiddle.net/YTZrj/4/